# Ubuntu 18.04, xampp : php shell command using base php version instead of xampp php version 7

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

on base ubuntu Iusing php5.6
on xampp using php7 for M2
when run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

giving error:

```
Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html
```

How to point to xampp php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to point xampp php by following command it will work:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

or add sudo if you are not root user, becaus its need to generate and delete some files

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Make sure you run the above command in root directory in ubuntu your magento root directory.

before above run this command :

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/your_mangento_root_folder
```

Comment: what is difference in actual answer & in yours ?

Comment: The new users get confused where the command should run the only thing i have mentioned is ..."Make sure you run the above command in root directory".

I am new to it once i get the your command i read it somewhere else so i feel it could be helpful to new users like me..

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad given you one upvote enjoy.. :)